# Unable to create an image hyperlink with xhtml2pdf

Tags: xhtml2pdf

Consider the following code:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

if __name__=="__main__":
    source_HTML = """<html>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQFNA.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
        <p>Stackoverflow</p>
    </a>
</body>
</html>"""

    output_filename = "output.pdf"

    # open output file for writing (truncated binary)
    result_file = open(output_filename, "w+b")

    # convert HTML to PDF
    pisa.CreatePDF(
        source_HTML,
        dest=result_file)

    result_file.close()
```

The html should render both an hyperlink image and a hyperlink text, but xhtml2pdf renders the image without the hyperlink and the text with the hyperlink. Is this an issue with the code above or a limitation/bug with the library? Thanks in advance for any help with the above issue.

Comment: I just came across the same issue on a PDF invoice I was trying to make with our logo linking back to our site. @user635090 were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get this too work but it is not very good.

You can add a &nbsp; before and after the img inside the A tag. And then set the font-size on the A tag to be the height of the image and then also set text-decoration to none.

So like I said this works but is not a great solution. I searched issues on xhtml2pdf's github page and cannot find anyone else with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was not terribly excited by the idea of having that workaround in my code so I decided to replace xhtml2pdf with weasyprint

Comment: Yeah I have used weasyprint also but had a some issues with it as well. What are your first impressions with it?

Comment: I found that it's much easier to work with weasyprint, Most of what works on the browser will look identical with weasyprint, and ironing out the remaining issues has been pretty easy so far.